# measure zero point in differentiable "almost everywhere"

Tags: real-analysis

I am a new student in leaning real analysis and still confused about "almost everywhere.

Definition:

> Points $x\in \mathcal{X}$ is true  except for $x$ in some **null set** (with measure $0$) ", we way it is true a.e.

Example:

"`Differentiable almost everywhere`" means  differentiable at every point outside a set of (Lebesgue) measure zero $\mu = 0$.

My question is:

Where is the set with measure zero in real line for example?

Hope to construct correct concept.

Comment: What do you mean the measure at 0 is 0? $\mu$ is a **set** function, so you are measuring sets. It only makes sense to talk of $\mu(\{0\})$, which does make sense and is 0 if $\mu$ is Lebesgue. Secondly, what do you mean measure zero in the real line? Are you asking for a subset of $ℝ$ with measure 0? It makes no sense to talk of $\mu(\{±∞\})$ with $\mu$ a measure on $ℝ$, and you specifically mentioned the real line.

Comment: I should ask where is the null set (measure 0) when discussing a function $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. For example, $f(x) = x^2$

Comment: Forget about measure zero for the moment, first do you understand what is a measure?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$, measure 0 is the length is $0$. Ex: $E=[a,a]$. $\mu(E) = 0$

Comment: What prior knowledge do you have? From the question it sounds that you're out on deep water here. Do you know the Lebesgue Integral? Do you know what a measure is? If you don't you should probably start there.

Comment: @sleevechen there are sets (some very weird) other than intervals with measure 0. I think it might be useful for you to work towards is the construction of Lebesgue measure via the infimum of open covers definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiability a.e. means that there is *some* null set $N$ such that your function (say) $f$ is differentiable on $ℝ \setminus N$. This null set depends on $f$. One example is
$$f(x) = |x|$$
This function has $N=\{0\}$.
Another is the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), and it is differentiable a.e. with derivative $0$, and is not differentiable on the Cantor set.
Yet another example is 
$$f(x) = 1$$
This function is differentiable a.e., in fact its differentiable everywhere but this doesn't stop you from setting $N=∅$.

Comment: What does the last sentence mean?

Comment: @sleevechen It means that every function that is "differentiable everywhere" is also "differentiable a.e.", going strictly by the definition. Why? Because we can find an $N$ that works in the definition of "differentiable a.e."; that $N$ is the empty set.